# Run HttpClient POST in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, task, dotnet-httpclient

I am using .net HTTPClient to save some data using POST REST API. The payload size for this API is around 10 MB. I am splitting my data in chunks and calling this POST API for each chunk. I have question mostly around approach:

1. I am planning to create single static instance of HTTPClient and will use same instance across application. What should be my approach? (create singleton or new client per chunk POST API call)
2. I would like to call all these chunk POST calls in parallel (using TASKS in .net). Is there any way to stop remaining tasks if any one task fails. I am looking for some sample code.

   ```
   _factory = new TaskFactory();
   _factory.StartNew(() =>
               //Call to async POST API using HttpClient                   
            ).ContinueWith((response) =>
                  {
                      if (!response.IsFaulted)
                      {
                         //Do something
                      }
                      else {
                          this._logger.Error("log the error");
                      }
                  });
   ```

Comment: Maybe a boolean variable that you set to true/false. The other tasks can then check that variable and stop if necessary.

Comment: You can also do it with a cancellation token. Here is some example code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955(v=vs.110).aspx, Also HTTPClient has a method for cancelling all pending requests. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.cancelpendingrequests(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Abhay I know this is an old post. But were you able to get this resolved? What did you finally use?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your calls are all to the same host, use a shared HttpClient instance.
2. There is no need to explicitly Create tasks using `TaskFactory.StartNew` in order to do I/O-bound asynchronous work in parallel. I would suggest using `Task.WhenAll`. Something like this:

   ```
   try {
       await Task.WhenAll(chunks.Select(MakeCall));
   }
   catch (Exception) {
       _client.CancelPendingRequests();
   }


   private async Task MakeCall(string chunk) {
       var response = await _client.PostAsync(chunk);
       if (!response.IsFaulted) {
           //Do something
       }
       else {
           this._logger.Error("log the error");
           throw new Exception("call failed!");
       }
   }
   ```